# Preserving Whitespaces in Soap response using xslt

Tags: xslt, soap, ibm-datapower

We are recieving soap response with spaces from backend application, when i see in datapower probe unformatted format i can see spaces. But Consumer team are recieving response without spaces from datapower webservice proxy.How can we send the unformatted response or how to preserve whitespaces within the response?
But when i test using soapUI I am getting response as expected with spaces.Please suggest

Actual Result :

```
    <restopic:SequencedText>
    <seqtxt:Sequence>00010</seqtxt:Sequence>
    <seqtxt:Text>% LOB: Facility, Professional Effective Date: 07/11/97</seqtxt:Text>
    </restopic:SequencedText>
```

Expected Result :

```
    <restopic:SequencedText>
    <seqtxt:Sequence>00010</seqtxt:Sequence>
    <seqtxt:Text>%   LOB: Facility, Professional                 Effective Date: 07/11/97</seqtxt:Text>
    </restopic:SequencedText>
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't trust the probe!
It will format messages according to what it "thinks" is correct and spaces might "disappear".
Make a XML File capture in the default domain and grab the archives from there to see how it really looks!

DataPower won't touch the XML element values so my guess is that it's either something happening after the message leaving DataPower or some conversion of character code or something messing up your spaces.

In the file capture you will be able to see both incoming and outgoig message and then you'll know how it looks.